# PHP error. " Undefined index" the data from the form won't insert into the mysql database

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-insert

it is a error in the VALUES in the php. It says it is a undefined index in every single value. 
I have tried for a long time now, but i can't figure out what the problem is. is it in my database or inside the code?
Please help me :)

```
<head>
    <title>Filmer</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Legg til filmer</h1>

    <form action="leggtil.php" method="post">
        <p>
            <label>Tittel: </title>
            <input type="text" name="tittel" placeholder="Tittel">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Utgitt: </label>
            <input type="text" name="utgitt" placeholder="Utgitt">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Sjanger</label>
            <input type="text" name="sjanger" placeholder="Sjanger">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Lengde: </label>
            <input type="text" name="lengde" placeholder="Lengde">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Alder: </label>
            <input type="text" name="alder" placeholder="Aldersgrense">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Format: </label>
            <input type="text" name="format" placeholder="Format">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Legg til">
        </p>
    </form>

    <?php
        $host="localhost";
        $username="root";
        $password="";
        $database="filmer";
        $table="filmer";

        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "conncected";
        mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "database found";

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO '$table'(videoid, tittel, utgitt, sjanger, lengde, alder, format) 
        VALUES ('', '$_POST[tittel]'. '$_POST[utgitt]', '$_POST[sjanger]', '$_POST[lengde]', '$_POST[alder]', $_POST[format])");
        ?>

</body>
```

Comment: A wonderful example of how to get hacked!  Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Answer (score 1):

The way you write $_POST variables is wrong :
`$_POST[tittel]` should be `$_POST["tittel"]`

Answer (score 1):

your php is incorrect, careful with quotes:

```
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "conncected";
    mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "database found";
      // remove the quotes around table names. they don't want quotes there
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (videoid, tittel, utgitt, sjanger, lengde, alder, format) 
    VALUES ('','" . $_POST['tittel'] . "','" . $_POST['utgitt'] "','" . $_POST['sjanger'] . "','" . $_POST['lengde'] . "','" . $_POST['alder'] . "','" .  $_POST['format'] . "')");
    ?>// when you refer to an array by string key, you must single or double quote it like $_POST['blah']. since you already have sinqgle quotes around your values (remember we are writing sql) you need to concatenate your variables
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP will execute every time, regardless of whether the form has been completed. The first time the form won't have been completed, so the $_POST array will be empty.

You need to make the PHP execution conditional. Try wrapping it like this:

```
If (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  // your code here

}
```

You'll need to give your `submit` button a name too:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Legg til" name="submit">
```

The syntax of your query is wrong. You should use backticks to enclose identifiers, not single quotes. Try this:

```
$myQuery = "INSERT INTO `$table` ( tittel, utgitt, sjanger, lengde, alder, format) 
    VALUES ('".$_POST['tittel']."', '".$_POST['utgitt']."', '".$_POST['sjanger']."', '".$_POST['lengde']."', '".$_POST['alder']."', '".$_POST[format]."')";
```

I've removed `videoid` from the query since it should be set to auto-increment; and I've replace one occurrence of a full-stop where a comma should be; I've rewritten the array references with single quotes.

Lastly, you should check the return status of your query:

```
$result = mysql_query($myQuery) or die(mysql_error());
```

Side-notes:

- Don't use `mysql_*()` - the functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*()` instead.
- You're open to SQL injection. You should escape your user inputs with `mysql_real_escape_string()`, or consider moving to prepared statements.

Comment: The error is gone, but the data won't be inserted into the database...